# Combination and Probability - Odds Solution

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the solution to working out the probability of picking 4 numbers and getting the odds that 1,2,3 or 4 will match a sequence of 4 numbers.  The number range is 1-10 with repeatable numbers, such as a pin code.

For example, the selected numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4. What are my odds of matching only 1 number correctly in its position, 2 numbers, or 3 numbers? Four numbers I have as it is 1 in total combinations.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Could you elaborate on your familiarity with combinatorics and probability theory, and describe exactly where you are stuck?

Comment: You used both the word "*probability*" and the word "*odds.*"  Be aware that these words are different and are not interchangeable.  They are used for similar things but the way in which they are represented is different.  The *probability* of drawing an ace out of a deck of cards is $\frac{1}{13}$.  The *odds* of doing so are $1$ for $12$ against.

Comment: Now... the total number of pin codes is $10^4$.  The number of pin codes who match number and position with `1234` no times would be $9^4$.  One time would be $4\times 9^3$, two times would be $\binom{4}{2}\times 9^2$, three times would be $\binom{4}{3}\times 9^1$ and all four times would be $\binom{4}{4}\times 9^0$.  This, counted trivially by picking which position(s) are the matches, and from left to right for the non-matches picking what non-matching digit is used in that position and applying the rule of product.  Dividing by $10^4$ gives the probability and completes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that's exactly what I needed, I was just missing the inclusion of incorrect possibilities.
If the numbers that are used could not be used again and therefore not repeatable, is it simply a case of leaving the initial coefficient and changing the multiplier to be 9*8*7 for match 1 only?